# Simple TypeScript helper function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to just make a static helper function which I can access from within any TypeScript module, I did find this post ([Can I declare a static private function in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468166/can-i-declare-a-static-private-function-in-typescript)) whose answer seems to be on the right track I need, but for some reason the TypeScript 1.4 compiler keeps throwing up this error:

***error TS2339: Property 'Dialog' does not exist on type 'typeof App'.***

This is the code I have implemented in my `utility.ts` file:

```
module App.Dialog {
    export module Modal {
        export function testHelper(link: string) {
            return 'worked';
        }
    }
}
```

and in my master file where I wish to call upon `testHelper` I have:

```
module App.Services {
    export class OrderService implements Interfaces.IService {
    ...
    App.Dialog.Modal.testHelper('test')
}
```

Also is this the best practice for various arbitrary helper functions? The actual helper I wish to create will be called getApiDate() and will return the precise date string format I need to be sent to my API and will need to be accessed quickly and easily within any module and ideally without instantiating a whole class, just as you would create a static class and method in C#.

Comment: do you have an `export` (or an `import`) at the root level of your file by any chance?

Comment: Both code samples above include the first lines in both files, top, export module, second export class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code works fine as shown:

[image]

You might be missing a `reference` tag. Complete code:

`utility.ts`

```
module App.Dialog {
    export module Modal {
        export function testHelper(link: string) {
            return 'worked';
        }
    }
}
```

`testHelper.ts`

```
/// <reference path="./utility.ts"/>

module App.Services {
    export class OrderService {
        constructor() {
            Dialog.Modal.testHelper('test');
        }
    }
}
```

PS: tip you might already know : difference between internal and external modules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Ah! The reference, I forgot to include it.... Genius! Thanks Basarat :) I will take a look at the video in case I haven't seen it; so finally my question, is the approach I am taking to create helper functions the best practice? How do you deal with these situations? I am using angular filters where appropriate though.

Comment: The method I use *right now* isn't well documented sadly. I need to create an oss template for it. I'm busy with https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript in my spare time right now.